# how to conntracking in suse9 ? ( ip_conntrack )

Tags: monitoring, iptables, suse, network-monitoring

I'm working on SUSE-10 Environment and am using /proc/net/ip_conntrack file to monitor net conntracking :

tcp 6 431982 ESTABLISHED src=.. dst=.. sport=34846 dport=993 **packets=169 bytes=14322** ...

But now I'm working SUSE-9 environment and the weevil also need this file to monitor net conntracking!

in the suse-9 /proc/net/ip_conntrack file show :

udp 17 30 src=.. dst=.. sport=57767 dport=53 [UNREPLIED] src=.. dst=.. sport=53 dport=57767

this do not show packets and bytes ! 
i needed packets and bytes

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure this is because the connection is [UNREPLIED] - as soon as you get a reply you will see bytes and packets.

If this is not true try to install the conntrack tool:

```
# which conntrack
/usr/sbin/conntrack
```

conntrack -L will show the data as the file /proc/net/ip_conntrack does. conntrack is great for monitoring it allows you to show events using: conntrack -E, this way you don't have to poll /proc/net/ip_conntrack anymore.

Comment: Thank you for your response. but i installed conntrack-tools .. It works just like previous file :udp 17 30 src=.. dst=.. sport=57767 dport=53 [UNREPLIED] src=.. dst=.. sport=53 dport=5776 .....this do not show packets and bytes ! i needed packets and bytes

Comment: What if the connection is replied? Do you get bytes in that case?

Comment: no! i can't get packets and bytes in the both case. I've enabled my firewall .. and I deleted my previous settings (firewall) , and I apply the new settings : for example ! iptables -A INPUT -p TCP --source-port 80 -j LOG ....! this < When I am using iptables -vnL command as the return value of pkt and bytes ! This is true method?

Answer (score 0):

SLES9's kernel is so old, I don't expect the feature to be enabled or to be there.

> this do not show packets and bytes ! i needed packets and bytes

Then you will have to update, or contract someone to tune your existing system (because I doubt anyone is going to take that pain for free). As it stands, enterprise distros currently [fare bad in providing recommended software sets](http://xtables-addons.sourceforge.net/ds-full.php).